# How to setup Odoo 10 Enterprise Edition in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: installation, odoo, enterprise

I have Odoo v10 EE at my end. I want to setup it at my end. I can't find any steps to setup it. Is anybody having any idea about it?

Comment: Does it support `deb` package or it's source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure they do not have [Help Guide](http://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/installing-odoo-10-ubuntu-16-04/)?

Comment: Yes. I have searched for it. But I couldn't find any kind of installation manual  or its related reference for it.

Comment: The help guide I referenced do have steps for installation.

Comment: But it is for Ubuntu 16.04. Will it work for Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Not sure but I think it will work as there is no such command / dependency in the installation that should have been added in 16.04

Comment: Ok. Let me try it.

Comment: Great! It is working. Thanks Abdul for your great help! :)